# How can i free dynamic memory that i allocated inside a "get" function?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm creating a function that will return an array that i have to allocate memory for,
but i can't find a way to make sure that memory will be deleted at the end of the program.

Here's the function:

```
int* RGB::getColor() const{
    int* arr = new int[3];

    arr[0] = red;
    arr[1] = green;
    arr[2] = blue;

    return arr;
}
```

Here's an example for its use:

```
int main(){
    int green;
    RGB test(50, 100, 150);

    green = test.getColor()[1];
}
```

Since it's not an object i can't delete anything inside the RGB's class destructor.
How can i make sure the memory is deleted at the end of the "getColor()" function use?
Thanks.

Comment: Dont return a raw pointer : use a smart pointer (or if possible, a `vector<int>`)

Comment: Newer textbooks for C++ should really have something like "always ask yourself if you can use a smart pointer instead of a raw one"

Comment: Also, you use-case does not need the array at all, why not just ask for the `green`?

Comment: You also can store them in a struct/class, which have 3 double value for R, G and B.
It's way easier to read.
You really shouldn't overuse pointers and arrays, use them only if you have no other choice.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this can save you some trouble:

```
class RGB
{
public:
    RGB(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        colors[0] = r;
        colors[1] = g;
        colors[2] = b;
    }

    int operator[](uint index)
    {
        // you can check index is not exceeding 2, if you want
        return colors[index];
    }

    int getColor(uint index)
    {
        // you can check index is not exceeding 2, if you want
        return colors[index];
    }

private:
    int colors[3];
};

int main(){

    RGB test(50, 100, 150);
    int green = test[1];
    // int green = test.getColor(1); // or you really want to use it this way
}
```

---

A modified version trying to achieve OP's request in comment:

```
struct Color
{
    int values[3];

    int operator[](uint index) const
    {
        // you can check index is not exceeding 2, if you want
        return values[index];
    }
};

class RGB
{
public:
    RGB(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        color.values[0] = r;
        color.values[1] = g;
        color.values[2] = b;
    }

    Color getColor() const
    {
        return color;
    }

private:
    Color color;
};

int main() {
    RGB test(50, 100, 150);
    int green = test.getColor()[1]; // no need to worry about memory management!
}
```

---

And actually it might be better if:

```
struct Color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

    enum Type
    {
        RED = 0,
        GREEN = 1,
        BLUE = 2,
    };

    int operator[](Type type) const
    {
        return values[type];
    }
};

class RGB
{
public:
    RGB(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        color.r = r;
        color.g = g;
        color.b = b;
    }

    Color getColor() const
    {
        return color;
    }

private:
    Color color;
};

int main() {
    RGB test(50, 100, 150);
    int green = test.getColor()[Color::GREEN];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still, i would like to have the options to return the whole "colors" array somehow,
a function that returns int* with an array including the 3 colors.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Not sure with your implementation detail, but if your `RGB` is somehow a simple class, returning (or using) a `RGB` object is itself a equally (and even better than) approach with returning `int` array. That's my opinion ;)

Answer (score 2):

> How can i make sure the memory is deleted at the end of the "getColor()" function use?

You can do that by capturing the result of the call and calling `delete[]` on it. This solution works, but it has problems that can be avoided.

Solution 1:

```
RGB test(50, 100, 150);

int *values = test.getColor(); // store result in variable here
green = values[1];
delete []values; // and release the memory here
```

This implementation is problematic, because it imposes responsibilities on the client code (i.e. if you don't call delete, you have leaks).

Here's an alternative solution:

Solution 2:

```
typedef std::tuple<int,int,int> RGBValue;

RGBValue RGB::getColor() const{
    return RGBValue{ red, green, blue };
}

auto green = std::get<1>( test.getColor() );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Since it's not an object i can't delete anything inside the RGB's class destructor.

Not being an object is not the issue. C-style arrays that have been allocated with `new[]` are freed with `delete[]`. But you should not free it in `RGB`'s destructor, because you've passed it outside the object and it might still be used.

You can free the memory with your current design:

```
int* colors = test.getColor();
green = colors[1];
delete[] colors;
```

But as you can see, it's not very good, because the caller must always remember to free something that they never allocated themselves.

Simplest design would be to return an instance of a container class which takes care of the memory:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 3> RGB::getColor() const{
    return {red, green, blue};
}
```